# Create a new file in Total Commander

Tags: total-commander

I want to create a new, empty file using Total Commander.

I have not been able to find out how to do this simple task, so I am asking here.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can create a new text file in Total Commander by pressing <kbd>SHFT</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> and entering a file name. The file will automatically open in the editor which is configured under `Configuration -> Options -> Operation -> Edit/View -> Editor for F4`.

Comment: Ai... Should have thought about that myself. :-(

Comment: @Tonny, I forget it always and look under every rock, but I can't find it. And then I feel so stupid when someone tells me it's Shift+F4.

Answer (score 7):

Press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> +<kbd>F4</kbd>. Simple. No need for any `menus` or the mouse.

Answer (score 6):

I saw in some blog (don't remember which - sorry) on a very simple way to do it which has a more TC authentic feel to it:

1. Go to **Start**-->**Change Start Menu**
2. Choose **Add Item** and give it the name **Create File**
3. In the **Command** text input, type - `cmd /c type null >`
4. In the **Parameters** text input, type - `?%N`
5. In the **Shortcut key** drop down, choose whatever you want. I chose <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> since it is easy for me to remember since <kbd>F7</kbd> creates a new directory.

This way it works exactly like creating a new directory - and you can hardly notice it actually opens a shell window (it closes in less than a second).

Comment: Explanation: `type null` or `type non-existent-filename.txt` - this command will fail and the output of the command will be a text string of length 0. That output (in reality, "no characters") will be saved `>` to the `%N` filename. `cmd /c` - this command is present to suppress the error message that the `type` command will produce.

Comment: Note also that if the `null` file exists in the working directory, the contents of that file will be saved as the contents of the file that we are creating.

Comment: So `cmd /c verify wrong-param >` would be better than `cmd /c type null >`

Comment: "`cmd /c` - this command is present to suppress the error message that the type command will produce." - this is wrong. What generates the "File not found" error message is the Total Commander. tcmd generates the error because it can't find the `type` command (tcmd apparently does not understand system verbs) (note that there are no type.exe and copy.exe files in Windows). Because tcmd does not understand the system verbs, we first launch the shell `cmd /c`, becuase _the shell_ (as compared to tcmd) understands system verbs.

Comment: @trismarck - Thank you for the explenations.

Comment: Even if Shift-F4 is neat, this one is nice too, as I will for sure forget the Shift-F4 at one point.

Answer (score 3):

Since TC Beta 9.0 (June 2016) this functionality is also present in the internal command list as cm_EditNewFile (2931 - Create+Open a new text file). This means you can now create a button that does this for you, if that's your thing.

RMB on a button bar -> Change -> Add a new button -> Enter command 'cm_EditNewFile'

Answer (score 0):

If it is about text files copy an existing file and rename it. Open it and select all, delete. I admit, that this is more difficult than in Windows Explorer but you will get used to it soon and often you copy files that are similar in its contents so modifying from an existing copy makes it easier than writing everything from scratch. At least this is the case when dealing with code.

Answer (score 0):

I went a bit old school with my way of doing it;
In the command bar at the bottom I type `copy con` followed by the file name and [Enter]. I then either paste the file contents or just press [F6], as I would have done 25 years ago in DOS. From there you can [F4] the file into your configured editor.

Answer (score 0):

To complement the answer, you can write in Configuration -> Options -> Operation -> Edit/View -> Editor for F4.

"explorer" "%1"

so default editor is used, for instance your text editor for .txt or open Word for .doc files.

Answer (score -2):

Unfortunately, you can't.

At least not directly with Total Commander. But you can invoke the standard Windows Explorer behavior from Total Commander.

Try this:

In the Total Commander `file/folders-panel` `right-click and hold` the mouse for about 1 second.
Total Commander will now fall-through to the normal Windows right-mouse menu you would normally get in Windows Explorer.

This menu's context depends on the object beneath the mouse-pointer. So you will only see the `New->Text document` (or whatever other file-format that's available on your system) option if you do this without any object beneath the cursor.

So you will have to click below the last file in the list in order to have nothing selected.
Even if the list fills the panel completely there is still a tiny (5 pixels or so) blank area below the last file that you can use.

Comment: Oh, OK. This is a bit stupid, but it helps.

Comment: Incorrect answer - see Tedesco's answer - http://superuser.com/a/387006/79348